# Problems with Parent and Child Classes

Tags: java, parent-child, bluej

I am trying to create a constructor for class HthsStudent, where it inherits variables and states from class Student. (Student inherited variables and states from class Person.)

The problem is, java doesn't like the way I'm trying to do it, and keeps telling me that what I'm doing is wrong, even though it is exactly what I did in class Student. It tells me that there is a "invalid method declaration, return type required" error, but I don't see a way to fix it.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Persn here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Person
{
String firstName;
String lastName;

public Person (String firstName, String lastName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String toString ()
{
   return lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
}





/**
 * Write a description of class Student here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Student extends Person
{
int gradeLevel;
private static int studentId = 0;

public Student (String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel)
{
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.gradeLevel = gradeLevel;

    if (gradeLevel > 5 || gradeLevel < 0)
    {
        gradeLevel = 0;
    }

    studentId = studentId + 1;
}

public int getLevel()
{
    return gradeLevel;
}

public String toString ()
{
    return lastName + ", " + firstName + "\nGrade Level: " + gradeLevel + "\nID #: " + studentId;
}
}




/**
 * Write a description of class HTHSStudent here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class HTHSStudent extends Student
{
double gpa;

public HthsStudent (String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel, double gpa)
{
    super(firstName, LastName, gradeLevel);
    this.gpa = gpa;

    if (gpa > 5.0 || gpa < 1.0)
    {
        gpa = 0.0;
    }


}

public String toString()
{
    return lastName + ", " + firstName + "\nGrade Level: " + gradeLevel + "\nID #: " + studentId + "\nGPA: " + gpa;
}
}
```

Comment: `"The problem is, java doesn't like the way I'm trying to do it, and keeps telling me that what I'm doing is wrong, even though it is exactly what I did in class Student."` -- What error messages? What problems? Please ask a complete question.

Comment: And this static: `private static int studentId = 0;` will bite you in the behind. Get rid of it.

Comment: The creators made Java reasonable enough to tell you what and why it's not liking something.

Answer (score 1):

You're not capitalizing the last class correctly. You've got:

```
class HTHSStudent extends Student
{
double gpa;

public HthsStudent (String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel, double gpa)
```

It should be

```
class HTHSStudent extends Student
{
double gpa;

public HTHSStudent (String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel, double gpa)
```

or even better:

```
class HthsStudent extends Student  {
    private double gpa;

    public HthsStudent (String firstName, String lastName, int gradeLevel, double gpa)
```

Note that for Java identifiers, capitalization matters

Also as noted in my comments, you've got another unrelated problem in that your studentId field should most definitely **not** be static. This field needs to be unique for *each* Student object, and if you make it static, it will become a property of the class, and thus be the same for all Students. If you made it static to fix a compiler error, then you fixed the wrong error. The correct fix is to not try to reference it in a static way, off the class.